# Choosing certificate for WiFi connection using my own UI in Windows XP Embedded

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, certificate, wifi

I'm working on a embedded system using Windows XP Embedded Standard. I try to setup a WPA2-Enterprise network using my own UI. There are a few client certificates installed and in an ordinary windows system you must click on a tiny icon in the taskbar to select a certificate used for the WiFi conncection.

Is there a way to either

1.) select the certificate by some API (Windows XP 'offically' seams to provide only PEAP not EAP-TLS)

- or -

2.) let the certificate selection dialog pop-up by some API call (even some hack with the explorer would be nice - explorer.exe is running but hidden in the background)?

In Windows7 point 1.) seams to be easy but changing the OS is not an option for my project.

Thanks for help

Tobias

Comment: Found a workaround: If only one certificate is stored in the MY certificate store this certificate is selected automatically w/o a dialog.